# How to integrate external library (slick) and utilize it into MarkoJS?

Tags: jquery, slick.js, marko

I am beginner to the **MarkoJS** technology. I am looking to create a carousel (`slider with multiple items`) component through MarkoJS. The issue i am facing to `load external libraries` (like Jquery) into MarkoJS. Not found any way to load external libraries and use them through marko.

The library i was looking to integrate with MarkoJS is **`jquery and slick (carousel)`**. It would be appreciated if one can suggest me a way for loading external **JS/Jquery** code into MarkoJS. So, that i can easily manipulate the DOM.

The thing, i was looking for is `DOM manipulation` through MarkoJS and how to use the `selectors in MarkoJS` ?

**Some possibilities already been tried:**

- Though, i am not using any library here. I am able to build a carousel slider through CSS which i don't want to.
- Second, have tried to built a logic to implement the slider through the Marko itself. But, again find a difficulty while selecting a `DOM elements`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of an existing jQuery plugin is fairly painless with Marko.  In the case of slick, it is available on `npm`, so you can `import` it in your template and attach it on mount to your component's root element:

```
import Slick from 'slick-carousel';

class {
  onMount() {
    this.slick = new Slick(this.el);
  }
}

<div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

You'll also need to make sure you've got a module bundler set up to get your dependencies to the browser.  Here's some examples using [webpack](https://github.com/marko-js-samples/marko-webpack) and [lasso](https://github.com/marko-js-samples/marko-lasso) with Marko.  You can also use the [starter project](https://github.com/marko-js-samples/marko-starter-demo), which has a bundler already set up.

Answer (score 0):

But if really need integrate jquery, there are some ways to do that:

```marko
import $ from 'jquery'

class {
  onMount() {
    $('.myElement', this.el).hide();
  }
}

<div>
  <div.myElement></div>
</div>
```